# How to go up on a tree in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Maybe the question is not suiting the topic i am going to approach

But i will try to explain the best i can:

I have a genealogical tree that has this structure:

```
data GT = Person Name Father Mother
        | unknown
     type Father  = GT
     type Mother  = GT
     type Name    = String
```

I need to find out the grandfathers of a given name:

grandfathers :: Name -> GT -> [Name]

this is the best i could do:

```
grandfathers :: Name -> GT -> [Name]
grandfathers s (Person x f m) = if (searchgrandson s f 0) then [x] else (grandfathers s f)
                    where
                       searchgrandson s unknown k = False
                       searchgrandson s (Person x f m) k = if s==x && k<2 then True
                                                                       else searchgrandson s f (k+1)
```

of course that for this tree it works, because my code goes all the way through the left side, ignoring the mother side, and giving only the grandfather, and not the grandmother right?

> $grandfathers "grandson" (Person "grandpa" (Person "son" (Person "grandson" unknown unknown ) unknown ) unknown )
>
> ["grandpa"]

EDIT:

after following the dfeuer advice:

```
avos_ :: Nome -> AG -> Int
avos_ s Desconhecida = 0
avos_ s l@(Pessoa x p m) = encontraneto s l 0
                       where
                        encontraneto s Desconhecida k = 0
                        encontraneto s (Pessoa x p m) k = if s==x then k
                                                                  else encontraneto s p (k+1) + encontraneto s m (k+1)
```

This gives me the depth of the tree where the grandson is, searching both sides. After this would be simple...

Thanks!

Comment: This seems a bit unclear to me. Are you trying to traverse the whole tree to find someone's name, so you can then find their grandfathers?

Comment: I need to find the grandfathers of a given name, for now, i think i can find one of the grandfathers. i know that the grandfather is always 2 levels above, that is why i use the Int 0, to search bellow that level.

Comment: I highly recommend that you write two completely separate functions: one to find the node in the tree corresponding to a specific name and one to find the grandfathers of a certain node. Then put the two of them together later to find the grandfathers of the person with a certain name.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to go about solving this problem is to decompose it into two functions. One of the functions will search the tree for zero or more matches against a name and return zero or more trees, starting from the place where the match occurred; the root of each tree will be the person that matches the name. The other function will simply take a tree and return zero, one, two, three or four names corresponding to the grandparents of the person at the root of the tree.

The types of the first function is easy:

```
searchPerson :: Name -> GT -> [GT]
```

The type of the second function is also straightforward

```
getGrandparents :: GT -> [Name]
```

Now, since the first function returns a list of `GT`, rather than a single `GT`, the second function should be mapped over the results of the first function (or, said other way, lifted to operate on lists of `GT`):

```
map getGrandparents (searchPerson x myGenTree)
```

Writing the second function (`getGrandParents`) is trivial and can be achieved with pattern matching, deconstructing the GT type up to the second level of nesting, but you would probably like to save yourself some typing and create a helper function to operate on each parent and return their parents.

The first function (`searchPerson`) is also trivial, and can be done in a couple of ways. One way is to simply use recursion looking for a match on a name and returning a list of all the subtrees that had a match. The other option is to simply return a list of every possible subtree in that tree, starting from any possible offset, and to use a filter to only keep those subtrees whose root is a match. The second option is more "wholesome" and equivalent to addressing a similar problem in lists (the function that returns all sublists is tails) so would probably appeal to some people more. You may think that the second approach is wasteful, but Haskell immutability and lazyness should make it pretty efficient too.

I quickly put together the code in my fpcomplete account and will gladly post the URL in a comment below if you ask, but I don't want to spoil the fun of coming up with the solution on your own.